# How to solve "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'"

Tags: python, function, plot, input, typeerror

I'm trying to plot a function but power message keeps popping up. I'm trying to raise x to the third power. How to solve?

```
 14 # use array for arithmetic operation
     15 x = [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
---> 16 y_list = x**3 - 3 * X
     17 
     18 plt.grid()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

I looked and tried other ways to resolve but I keep getting the same error

Comment: `x` is a list.  You can't raise a list to a power.  What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to iterate over x and get your y_list values.

```
x = [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
y_list = [x**3 - 3 * x for x in x]

print(f"Resulting y list = {y_list}")
```

Output: `Resulting y list = [-970, -702, -488, -322, -198, -110, -52, -18, -2, 2, 0, -2, 2, 18, 52, 110, 198, 322, 488, 702, 970, 1298]`